# VB6 and Delphi - TStringList is free by VB

Tags: delphi, vb6, ocx, tstringlist

I have the following situation:
An object is instantiated in VB6 using OCX made ​​in Delphi.
when I

```
...
Dim x As New spdComponent
Set x = spdComponent.ConverterType (XML)
count = x.item.count
TXT = ""
...
```

Count receives the value of all items of the TStringList OCX correctly, but soon the line below, where TXT gets empty, the value of 'x.item.cout' is lost.
When I debug in Delphi, in reality what happens is a TStringList be released from memory, but this happens without any sense (it seems that there is a conflict of interest between Delphi and VB).
Searching here and on google, I saw that many commented about not using TStringList but PChar, it would be a more appropriate way of working, but the question remains as to make use of C # 2005 and the same OCX, the problem is not occurs. (as in other languages​​, only in VB 6, so far).

Well, I have evidence that the VB kills the object (TStrinList) because for him, that object is not longer necessary, but it does.
One strange thing that happens is, if I

```
count = spdComponent.ConverterType(XML).item.count
```

It's work, do all the necessary processes without any error, but that first case, the error still remains.

Has anyone encountered similar problems?

Thanks guys, anyone who can give me a hand ... will be grateful

Comment: its sound how some type binding between txt and your component. Put dim x as spdComponent "newline" x = new spdComponent instead of dim x as new spdComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIR, VB Classic uses reference count semantics for management of memory. This means, somewhere in your code, all references to the instance created by `spdComponent.ConverterType(XML)` are cleared (pointing to `Nothing`) or got out of scope.

EDIT: in you code you're destroying the instance created by `Dim x As New spdComponent` when you do `Set x = spdComponent.ConverterType (XML)`. Maybe you could test this:

```
 ' Removed the instantiation on the declaration
Dim x As spdComponent
Set x = spdComponent.ConverterType (XML)
count = x.item.count
```

And tell us if something changed...

Comment: Still return "Method of Type ConvertType" Interface "failed"

Comment: I implemented my program in VB.Net and it works normally.
Adapted to what was requested, and it worked. I did the reverse, took the VB.Net code and put a button and ran, but still giving the same message, in addition to the EurekaLog tells what is happening "Multi Free Memory," Something is causing the elimination my TStringList without "authorization." What makes me question whether it is the Delphi and VB conflicting.
Making debug my DLL, I realize that StringList ends, "just out of nowhere." For this reason I think VB and Delphi are coming into conflict of interest. (Sorry about my english)